# What is the Time Complexity of a array sorted in the ascending order if it is passed to Reversort Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

A reversort Algorithm is defined as the following:

```
Reversort(L): 
for i := 1 to length(L) - 1
    j := position with the minimum value in L between i and length(L), inclusive
    Reverse(L[i..j])
```

I understand that the time complexity is O(n^2) for a array

But for a array which is already sorted(in ascending) what is the complexity?

Will it remain same or will it become O(n)?

Comment: I would simply time it for different n to get a first idea.

Comment: What is the cost of "position with the minimum value in L between i and length(L), inclusive" ?

Comment: @MrSmith42: that's a poor suggestion, sorry.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: If you are not sure if something is O(n) or O(n²) profiling is a very quick way to be quite sure which one it is. After that you need of cause proof it base on the source code.

Comment: @MrSmith42: I disagree with this. Timing algorithms often gives wrong insights. PCs are very poor RAM models. And an empirical guess between O(n) and O(n²) makes no sense.

Comment: @MrSmith42: using this approach, one would conclude that Quicksort has linear behavior !

Comment: @Yves Daoust; I'm 100% sure thatfor worst case input and a proper range of different n values you'll see O(n²) timings for quicksort. No matter how bad the PC is as a model O(n²) will never look like O(n) for big enough n.

Comment: @MrSmith42: you seem to have little experience in that matter. Unless you choose the input data carefully, the O(n²) cases will remain in the tail of the distribution and are extremely rare (good pivot selection strategies will strive to make them even more rare). And a beginner will see no difference between O(n) and O(n log n) behaviors, not counting the dispersion and sources of bias in the measurement.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: My suggestion was related to the question (so specific sorted input) and only the need to see the difference between O(n) and O(n²) that should be possible also for a beginner. I agree that timing is only a tool to get a first impression. Formal analysis must follow afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still takes quadratic time. Not for reversals, since `j` will always be `i` so each reversal takes O(1). But for finding the minimum values.

(Finding the minima *could* be done faster if you for example additionally kept the remaining elements in a min-heap (leading to overall O(n log n) time), but that would really have to be stated. As it's written, it's doing a full search through the remaining part each time.)

Comment: But the algorithm will always encounter the minimum element at the beginning of the  subarray to be searched, i.e it will always find the minimum element at the `i` th which is where the search for the minimum begins. so shouldn;t the operation for finding the minimum also take O(1) time?

Comment: @AkashKp The minimum is always already there, yes. *But the algorithm doesn't know that.* It must look through the rest to know that it is the minimum.